# Complex Integral result proof

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-integration

*Question*: Let $f \colon D \to \mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function defined on an open subset $D$ of $\mathbb C$, and suppose that $z_0 \in D$ is a double zero of $f$. Show with justification that for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ we have
$$
\int_{|z-z_0|= \epsilon} \frac{z-z_0}{f(z)}dz = \frac{4\pi i}{f''(z_0)}.
$$

I´ve tried defining $f(z)$ as $f(z)=g(z)(z-z_{0})^2$ and then applying Cauchy's formula for the second derivative, replacing $f(z)$ as stated, but i couldn't reach the intended result.

If someone could guide me or enlight me on the process i would appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: the integrand is asymptotic to $\frac{2}{f^{\prime\prime}(z_0)}(z-z_0)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and the "setting up" of my first question here, as well the hints or suggestions. I have reached the intended result, but i cannot upvote the hint **@krm2233** made

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @J.G.'s hint, you were almost there when you suggested writing $f$ as $(z-z_0)^2g(z)$ -- since $f$ has a zero of order $2$ at $z_0$, we have $f(z) = \frac{1}{2!}f''(z_0).(z-z_0)^2.g(z)$, where $g(z_0) = 1$ (and $f''(z_0) \neq 0$). Consider what you get if you just use this slightly finer description of $f$ near $z_0$ in the integral you are trying to evaluate.